# Help with Taylor Series Expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

I don't know how to exactly approach this,

[image]

Do I do the taylor series expansion individually on each part or. I just need some guidance.

Comment: Why do you need to Taylor this?

Comment: It's part of a much bigger problem and for this, I have to apply the taylor series.

Comment: And you need to expand in all the variables? Around zero? Up to what order?

Comment: All variables, 2nd order

Comment: 2nd order changes things significantly. Please, add this information to your question. Then I would simply suggest to expand all the functions to 2nd order and simplifty the result, leaving out any higher order terms you obtain. It's just a little bit of algebra

Comment: @YuiryS apologies. I was meant to say 1st order.

Comment: 1st order is even more simple than 2nd (obviously). Just expand every function, and then simplify the resulting expression as needed